# find the maximum element in each column in a matrix using C?

Tags: c

I want to printf the largest value of every column element
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
So i want to printf 7 8 9 because they are the largest numbers in the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>

    int main( void ) {
        int a[10][10],c[10],max[10],min[10],n,j,i,tmp,r;
        printf("Vuvejdane na vhodni danni:\n");
        printf("Vuvedete broi redove i broi stulbove n=");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<n;j++) {
                do {
                    printf("Vuvedete A[%d][%d]:",i,j);
                    scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
                } while (((a[i][j])<-500) || ((a[i][j])>500));
            }
        }
        printf("Izvejdane na vhodni danni :\n");
        for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for (j=0;j<n;j++) {
                printf("%5.1d ",a[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Greetings! How to find the max element of every column?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If you wrote the above code, you shouldn't have a hard time doing that.

Comment: I know... I am not good in C, thats why i need help...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop that iterates columns by rows:

```
// mx is array of maximum by column
for (j=0;j<n;j++) {
    mx[j]= a[0][j];
    for (i=1;i<n;i++) {
        mx[j] = max(mx[j],a[i][j]);
    }
}
```

and `max(a,b)` is a function that returns the maximum of the 2 arguments.

Comment: Please note that, while it's immaterial with OP's code arrays sizes, in general it would be more cache friendly to traverse the matrix rowwise (just switch the order of the loops).